# Deposit money to credit card

Tags: credit-card, money-transfer, deposits

Let's say I know a credit card number and the card doesn't belong to me, can I deposit money on that credit card? The receiver will not object getting extra money. But is this possible and how you do it? Let's assume that the credit card is Mastercard, in case there are different practices with other cards.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would need a merchant account with a bank to do that.

Comment: Do you mean deposit money, or do you mean pay someone else's balance?

Comment: I mean to deposit money.

Comment: What's the difference, really? I have on occasion overpaid my bill, and nobody has ever done anything about it.

Comment: @DJClayworth There was a similar question recently [http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13914/credit-card-charge-from-the-bank]. Eventually they will send a check to the card owner.

Comment: @DJClayworth -  I think the difference is some card issuers don't want to accept money unless there is a balance, so to me, a deposit sounds like he might want to add more than the balance on the card.

Comment: So, a credit card works to provide a short time dynamic load (credit) to someone. That someone then has to pay the given credit bill (monthly for example). So it seems there's no meaning to deposit money into a credit card because it isn't intended to hold money - just hold a debt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A credit card is not a bank account.  It is, essentially, a contract to extend a line of credit on an as needed basis through a process accepted by the provider(purchase through approved vender, cash advance, etc).  There is no mechanism for the bank to accept or hold a deposit.  While most card issuers will simple retain the money for a period of up 30-60 days to apply toward transactions, I have had a card that actually charged a fee for having a negative balance in excess of $10 for more than 30 days(the fee was $10/month).

So no you can not **DEPOSIT** money on any credit card.  You need an account that accepts deposits to make a deposit.

Answer (score 4):

Is this a hypothetical question? It sounds like a combination of "can my amount owed on a card go negative (i.e. a credit) and can I deposit to someone else's XXX account. My wife kept her last name. when I pay her charge card I've never gotten rejected, I don't see why this wouldn't work if a stranger gave me their number and address to make payment.

Comment: Well, your hypothesis has nothing to do with my case. Sorry I'm not going to details, I'm just trying to get a general answer. By the way, how do you pay your wife's card? That's the kind of information I might be looking after. If it's a bill, then you are not answering my question.

Comment: I'll say this. I pay only by knowing the account numbers and card issuer address. It would appear pointless to say much else. I'm actually sorry I tried to answer this non-question in the first place. I learned a lesson here.

Comment: So this answer has nothing to do with the credit card? You just deposit money to the account? If I understand correctly, you cannot just put money into the credit card, a card charge is needed?

Answer (score 0):

JohnFx is more experienced than I am but I have paid off friends cards before. It was as simple as asking them the routing number of the bank that gave them the card and setting up an ACH with their card number.

I guess this might be against some banks T&C but the CU I used to carry out the ACH gave me the go ahead as long as I did not dispute the payment later.